# Dual primary / dual secondary transformer heat up

Tags: power, transformer, heat

I've built [this](https://github.com/valer-cara/robot) 220v DC motor controller. I use a 2x110v - 2x15v transformer to power up the stator.

[image]

The transformer is a [Myrra 45064](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/41312.pdf) with the primary windings connected as follows: pins 1 and 9 connected to the mains, pins 4 and 6 in short.

On the secondary windings, i've connected pin 12 and 19 to a rectifier, and 14 and 17 in short.

When I plug it in at 220v AC, the transformer heats up very fast and outputs ~12V out of the expected 30V. Didn't keep it powered more then 6 seconds.

I thought that this pin configuration should connect the 2 halves of the transformer in series and output 15+15V.

Am I connecting them wrong, or there could be another cause for the high current through the transformer?

P.S.: The schematic on github shows a 3 port primary winding, however, the board is built with the connections done as explained above.

Comment: Try open secondary first and see that you have ~30V, then connect a few hundred ohms to it and see if it behaves as it should. If yes, then check the bridge, the capacitor, the wires, more than that I cannot help, this is a "blind answer" for my part.

Comment: Have you tried it with the load disconnected? It sounds like you're simply overloading the transformer.

Comment: I've totally isolated the transformer, ran 220 through the extreme pins in the primary, short the middle primary pins. I've also separated the 2 secondaries. Voltage/secondary ~6V instead of 15. The trafo is new. No idea what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Farnell page](http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/level5/module.jsp?moduleId=en/549641.xml) has a little better description of the wiring needed:

```
Primary Pin Connections        |    Secondary Pin Connections           
Style   0V  115V    0V   115V  |    0V  Vsec    0V  Vsec
UI39    1   4       9    6     |    17  19      14  12
```

It looks like connecting per this table parallels the primary winding to set the turns ratio for 115V input.

Based on that idea, it looks to me like pins 1 and 6 should see the AC and pins 4 and 9 should be connected together, to maintain the correct phasing of the primary.

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed the issue. I totally missed that wiring info. Fixed now :)